# Getting stats of employee and manager taks from a table

Tags: sql, oracle

--I have a table like as follows:

```
create table EmpTask(emp varchar(10), task_no number, mgr varchar(10));

insert into EmpTask(emp, task_no, mgr) values('aaa',111, 'mmm');
insert into EmpTask(emp, task_no, mgr) values('aaa',222, 'mmm');
insert into EmpTask(emp, task_no, mgr) values('bbb',333, 'mmm');
insert into EmpTask(emp, task_no, mgr) values('bbb',444, 'mmm');
insert into EmpTask(emp, task_no, mgr) values('mmm',555, 'nnn');
insert into EmpTask(emp, task_no, mgr) values('ooo',666, 'nnn');

insert into EmpTask(emp, task_no, mgr) values('kkk',777, 'lll');
insert into EmpTask(emp, task_no, mgr) values('kkk',888, 'lll');
insert into EmpTask(emp, task_no, mgr) values('lll',999, 'ppp');

insert into EmpTask(emp, task_no, mgr) values('ppp',000, 'zzz');
insert into EmpTask(emp, task_no, mgr) values('nnn',001, 'zzz');

zzz is a top level manager.
```

--Now for a given manager name I need a query which will return manager row and count of tasks under him/his directs and in later rows individual employee and count of their task.

--For example for manager 'nnn' stats should be displayed like as follows:

```
user  task_count
-----------------
nnn         7
  mmm       5
    aaa     2
    bbb     2
  ooo       1
```

--In above output mmm is having 5 issues( 2 each from aaa and bbb and 1 from himself). In same way nnn is having total 7 issues(5 issues from mmm, 1 from ooo and 1 in his own queue).

--for manager 'mmm' stats should be displayed like as follows:

```
user  task_count
-----------------
  mmm       5
    aaa     2
    bbb     2
```

--If there is no directs like 'aaa' then query should return that employess stats only like

```
user  task_count
-----------------
aaa    2
```

Comment: The <plsql> tag says: _Questions about PL/SQL should probably be tagged "oracle" as well. Questions with regular DML or DDL statements should be tagged with "sql" and "oracle", NOT with "plsql"._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following would help you. I have used SQL Server as the database as you havent specified a db.

```
with cte
 as(select emp,task_no,mgr,cast(emp as varchar(1000)) as concat_val,cast(1 as int) as lvl
      from emptask
    where emp='mmm'
    union all
    select a.emp,a.task_no,a.mgr,cast(concat(concat_val,'/',a.emp) as varchar(1000)),cast(b.lvl+1 as int) as lvl
      from emptask a
      join cte b
        on b.emp=a.mgr
    )
    select distinct 
           a.emp
          ,concat(replicate(' ',a.lvl),a.emp)         
          ,a.mgr              
          ,a.lvl
          ,count(b.concat_val) as cv_2
     from cte a
     join cte b
       on b.concat_val  like concat('%',a.emp,'%')
group by a.emp
          ,concat(replicate(' ',a.lvl),a.emp)
          ,a.task_no
          ,a.mgr      
          ,a.concat_val
          ,a.lvl
order by a.lvl
```

You would plug in the value of emp='mmm' to be based upon the mgr you wish to find out the tasks which are under her/him.

For Oracle i tried the following

```
with data
as (
SELECT emp,
       mgr,
       RPAD('.', (level-1)*2, '.') || emp AS tree,
       level as lvl,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT emp AS root_id,
       LTRIM(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(emp, '-'), '-') AS path,
       CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF AS leaf,
       task_no
FROM   (select * 
          from EmpTask
        union all
        select 'zzz' as emp,null as task_no,null as mgr
          from dual /* Need to add the top most emp as a new row*/
        union all
        select 'ccc' as emp,-111 as task_no,'bbb' as mgr
          from dual
        union all
        select 'bbb' as emp,-110 as task_no,'ccc' as mgr
          from dual  
       )
START WITH emp='zzz'
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE mgr = PRIOR emp /*This fixes case where emp reports to mgr reports to same emp*/
)
select a.emp
       ,max(a.tree)
       ,count(distinct b.task_no)
       ,max(a.lvl)
  from data a
  join data b
    on b.path  like '%'||a.emp||'%'
group by a.emp    
order by 4
```

Have updated to include the conditions you have mentioned.

- Loop in Cycle data. (Remedy: Include CONNECT BY NOCYCLE keyword)
- Issue with zzz who is the top most employee (Remedy: Need to create a
  row in the record set with the top most person in the food    chain)

Here is the updated link that caters to both these scenarios.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6ba99eb591a5768b8cb9487cf39f37f9

Comment: This query is needed for Oracle DB. Could you please let me know what changes in above query has to be done? I am not familiar with SQL server.

Comment: Hi George,

with above oracle query for top level manager 'zzz' it is not returning any row.

Also for some of the manager values in my production data I am getting below error:
"ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data"
Could you please let me know when this error is encountered in such queries?

Comment: You must be having loops in the hierarchial query. ie a emp is reporting to a  mgr and that mgr reports to the same emp. To fix that use CONNECT BY NOCYCLE mgr= prior emp

Comment: Thanks a lot George.
I have one last query regarding this. Could you please let me know the modified query when we want to see rows of given manager and his immediate directs only but stats should be from leaf level.

like for 'nnn' it should return below result.

user  task_count
-----------------
nnn         7
  mmm       5
  ooo          1

Comment: So in this case you can add the criteria in the having clause "having max(a.lvl)<=2". Here is the dbfiddle link. -->https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c4ab180ccd067fa1508baac0bb7e6eb3

Comment: Hi George,
My actual query returns "ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns". In my table there are more emp and manager hierarchy than in above table. Could this be the reason for above error?

Comment: Dont think so, you are probably unioning this query or inserting this to another table and not all columns are properly aligned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203579/discussion-between-subhash-tiwari-and-george-joseph).

Comment: Hi George,
I am getting "ORA-01789: query block has incorrect number of result columns" because my table has few more columns. I added one additional column in table given in this questiobn and that also failing with same error.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5402267ab5cfc85a15ad83056133d6ad

Comment: You added a new column(dummy_col) and after that you have a select * from Emptask union all select columns_excluding_dummy_column from dual which is causing the error